# Excel VBA code to compare system date with date in the worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, date

I want a vba code to compare the system date with the date i mentioned in a row (A) in excel worksheet. If the dates are equal then it should compare the system time and the time mentioned in a row (B). Eg: If the time mentioned in the sheet is 7 30 PM and the system time is 7 PM, it should calculate the time between and display. If the date in the sheet does not matches then it should leave.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Paste your code attempt so we can help you.

Comment: With what accuracy would you like the comparison? Could be seconds or minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should display hours and minutes.

Comment: @ Jlili Amen.. Thanks.. Im totally new to this code and just started. Help me with the code if you have any as per my requirement

Comment: If your time is listed in cell A1, what cell would you like the calculated difference to appear?

Comment: You should post code what you tried. It is more better than you request. So, we can think more effectively. Okay..!

Comment: @ Excel Hero - Difference should appear in mail.

Comment: What do you mean "mail"?

Comment: I have a code to display the mail content... The thing is it should look for the system date and date in sheet and It should display the mail content for all the cell the date matches.

Comment: You are going to get pummeled here with this type of question because you have not posted specific code that you need help with.

Your description is vague, and as a follow-up after your initial question you are referring to the text of an email. There is zero chance of anyone here knowing the details of how to insert the time difference because we do not know anything about the emails and how they are stored, etc. BUT... I just posted an answer to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together a small procedure to get you started. It assumes the date/time in the worksheet is in cell A1. If the system date is the same as the date in cell A1, it then compares the system time with the time in cell A1. If they are the same to the minute then nothing happens.

However, if they are different then the number of minutes by which they are different appears in cell B1.

Here is the code:

```
Public Sub DateTimeCheck()

    Dim d  As Double
    Dim s1 As String
    Dim s2 As String

    s1 = Format([a1], "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm")
    s2 = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm")

    If Left$(s2, 10) = Left$(s1, 10) Then
        d = TimeValue(Right$(s2, 5)) - TimeValue(Right$(s1, 5))
        If d Then
            [b1] = d * 1440
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Now, if you have more cells with dates in column A and you want to compare them as well, then you will need to modify this code so that it "processes" all of them.

As far as writing the difference in minutes to the email... we would need much more detail for that!

Comment: Thanks a ton.. yes i agree with you that without the correct data, its difficult to interpret. I ill startup with this code and let you know if i face any issue with proper data.

Comment: Honestly, can someone explain why this answer was down-voted? I just want to know because while the question was vague, I could see where the OP wanted to go and offered help. This kind of nonsense (and this is not the first time) makes sharing my knowledge here not worth it.